# iOS app crash due to Exception 0xdeadfeed !! whats the reason of 0xdeadfeed?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.5

```
Incident Identifier: 59F8A919-279A-4C9E-9B58-FFFE9C01F9E9
CrashReporter Key:   73755578964009d66f989a2277500f68dc02d973
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
OS Version:          iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Kernel version:      Darwin Kernel Version 11.0.0: Sun Apr  8 21:51:26 PDT 2012; 
root:xnu-1878.11.10~1/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8930X
Date:                2013-02-12 11:47:12 +0500
Exception Code:      0xdeadfeed
Reason:              Timeout waiting for service to spawn
Thermal Level:       -1
Thermal Sensors:    failed to load sensor values

Frontmost process PID:    7751
Frontmost process PID:    51
Jetsam Level:             28
Free Pages:             1642
Active Pages:           9820
Inactive Pages:         5087
Purgeable Pages:        4327
Wired Pages:           14299
Speculative Pages:       297
Throttled Pages:       32563
Busy Buffer Count:         0

Process 0 info:
resident memory bytes:  32129024
page faults:                694
page-ins:                     0
copy-on-write faults:         0
user   time in task: 136936.597192 seconds
system time in task:     0.000000 seconds
```

//Whats the reason of:-

```
   Exception Code:      0xdeadfeed
```

Comment: It says timeout waiting for service to spawn. What is your app trying to do when it crashes?

Comment: sending tweet on background thread

Comment: are you sure you are not doing any of UI Changes on background thread  just check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969820/iphone-application-my-application-crash/13970179#13970179